# Multiple if-else statements into polymorphism in c++

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

I've read through several issues regarding the topic at interest however still have a difficult time coming to a conclusion. I apologise in advanced if this is a redundant question.

To get to the point, my problem is trying to implement a logical payoff test. For example, a financial product may have several conditions and depending on each condition the payoff will differ. However, the how many conditions are unknown until the contract is received. Goal is to program a payoff implementation while not hard coding each if statement whenever a new product comes. For example I receive first a contract with only one condition. The next day I receive a contract with two condition etc. I understand that this problem can be tackled with polymorphism but I have a difficult time how.

The payoffs themselves are coded using polymorphism.

For example I have an abstract generic payoff class with concrete generic payoff classes.

```
class cPayoffAbstract
{
private:
public:
   cPayoffAbstract(){}
   virtual cPayoffAbstract* clone() const = 0;
   virtual ~cPayoffAbstract(){} 
   virtual double operator()(double& x) const = 0;
};

class cPayoffConcrete1 : public cPayoffAbstract
{
private:
   double y;
public:
   cPayoffConcrete1(double& argY);
   virtual cPayoffConcrete1* clone() const;
   virtual ~cPayoffConcrete1(){}
   virtual double operator()(double& x) const;
};

class cPayoffConcrete2 : public cPayoffAbstract
{
private:
   double y;
public:
   cPayoffConcrete2(double& argY);
   virtual cPayoffConcrete2* clone() const;
   virtual ~cPayoffConcrete2(){}
   virtual double operator()(double& x) const;
};
```

Then I have another class to define the interface of a more complex payoff.

```
#include <cPayoffAbstract.h>
#include <SmartPtr.h>
#include <vector>
class cConditionalPayoff
{
private:
   // Some data members
public:
   cConditionalPayoff(const SmartPtr<cPayoffAbstract>& argPayoffPtr1, const SmartPtr<cPayoffAbstract>& argPayoffPtr2);

   // some methods ...
   double fConditionalPayoff(const std::vector<double>& argXs, double& argY, double& argZ) const;
};
```

Suppose there is a contract with few conditions and depending on the conditions will have different payoff which is implemented in the generic payoff class.

```
double cConditionalPayoff::fConditionalPayoff(const std::vector<double>& argXs, double& argY, double& argZ) const
{
   for (unsigned long i = 0; i < argXs.size(); i++)
   {
      if (argXs[i] > argY) { return dmPayoffPtr1->operator()(argXs[i]); }
      else
      {
          if (argXs[i] < argZ) { return dmPayoffPtr2->operator()(argXs[i]); }
          else { return argX[i]; }
      }
   }
}
```

The problem comes when for example a different contract with similar payoffs but more conditions are designed in the contract. Then the above if statements must be recoded in or  another method has to be implemented.

Thus, the goal is to implement the `fConditionalPayoff` in a dynamic way instead of coding in ifs ad hoc.

I hope my re-edit helps clarify some misunderstanding. I apologise if there were.

Thank you again.

Comment: Seems like it'd be better to have this data-driven, rather than code-driven.

Comment: I see where your approach. However, if the data structure was broken then there could be problems lurking around. Additionally, if there were other conditions but the conditions are not known ahead of time then data-driven could break down? For example there are 4 conditions instead of 2.

Comment: Its not clear to me, what you want to achieve, but if you have an unknown type, polymorphism may not be the right way to tackle this. You need to know about every type, if you want to address type dependend if statements with polymorphism

Comment: @xeed The goal is to code a more elegant pattern and not use too many nasty {if} statements.

Comment: Yeah I understood that, but its not clear to me, what you want to do with these if statements. What exactly are the inputs. What kind of types do you have. As I wrote, if you don't know any of them, you are going to have a bad time with polymorphism

Comment: @xeed I edited my question. I hope that it clarifies what you do not understand.

Comment: Um, your changes did not clarify anything. The last codeblock is the problem. What is what. You write argXs ... nobody knows what this should be. Does the size of this array varies or are there getting passed more additional args, which should be compared with your vector.
I know you are trying to ask in a more general way, but i can't tell  you which pattern to use, if i don't get what you are actually doing. Try to give some examples of altering conditions.

Comment: If you have completly undefined behaviour in your contracts, the contract itself should define, what his vars mean. It should have a vector of conditions, that you could check. Sorry if i dont get it right, but basically, i think, you have a function with complete random input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of your problem is that you want to dynamically add behaviors to your Contract object.
In this case, I think what you need is the Decorator Pattern.

You can find its description here : http://www.oodesign.com/decorator-pattern.html

and some explanations here : http://oreilly.com/catalog/hfdesignpat/chapter/ch03.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your suggestion means that in the already payoff class, use the already programmed payoff interface but in the implement the payoff in a different way?

Comment: Yes that's about it. I think the example shown page 95 of the "Head First : Design Pattern" (given in the link) is actually quite close to what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could split logic into two parts (pseudocode):

```
class PayOffProcessor;

class PayOffProcessor1 : public PayOffProcessor { ... };
class PayOffProcessor2 : public PayOffProcessor { ... };
class PayOffProcessor3 : public PayOffProcessor { ... };

class PayOffProcessor
{
    virtual void process() = 0;

    static PayOffProcessor * processorForData(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        static PayOffProcessor1 processor1;
        static PayOffProcessor2 processor2;
        static PayOffProcessor3 processor3;
        if (x > y)
        {
            return &processor1;
        }
        if (x < z)
        {
            return &processor2;
        }
        return &processor3;
    }
};

double myclass::conditionalPayoff(std::vector<double>& x, double& y, double& z) const
{
     for (unsigned long i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
     {
         processorForData(x, y, z)->process();
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Thus, basically have a class that takes care of the logical implementation and in the loop make a call to the process method in evaluating it?

Comment: Yes, just separate selection of specific class into another function and let C++ polymorphism do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism can only be applied, if you know about all the possible combinations of condition, so you can derive from your abstract class for each one of them and implement the checking function for these conditions.

If you don't know what conditions are possible, they should be defined by a user input or whatever. You could approach this like the following:

```
Input: Vector<Values>, Vector<ConditionType>, Vector<ConditionValue>, Vector<PayOffType>
```

In the ConditionType Vector you write sth. like a string of "<" or ">" or sth.

```
void checkConditions(vector<double> values, vector<string> condType, vector<double> condValues, vector<string/int> PayOfftype) {
  for(int i=0; i<values.size(); i++) {
    switch(condType[i]) {
      case("<"):
        if(values[i] < condValues[i]) {
           PayOff po = getPayOffByType(PayOfftype[i]);
           po.payoff();
        }
        break;
      case(">"):
        ...
      break;
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

You could pass into this a default payoff type, if no condition applies as well.